# Apache Module - block an IP address

Tags: apache, module

Can i block an IP address in apache module?

i searched it, but it comes up with no answer, is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can block using iptables. with a simple rule. 
But if you have concerns over some ip address causing DOS attacks or something then you can add it to your black list automatically by using DOS deflate program. I am providing it below for your convenience.

This script will help protect dos attack on our servers. We will use DDos deflate method.

This method will use iptables to block any dos traffic. and will create a cronjob that will execute every minute to execute the script, script will then monitor any threats and stops them using iptables.

```
1. Install the deflate script

    wget http://www.mattzuba.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/ddos_deflate-0.7.tar.gz

    tar -xf ddos_deflate-0.7.tar.gz

    cd ddos_deflate-0.7

    sudo ./install.sh

2. now the above script is installed in the directory /usr/local/ddos


    cd /usr/local/ddos


you will see a file called ddos.conf, edit the file


    vi ddos.conf
```

Here you will see various options, look for ##### How many connections define a bad IP? Indicate that below.

```
NO_OF_CONNECTIONS=xyz

change no of connections to 200

    NO_OF_CONNECTIONS=200
```

Where 200 is the number of total connections allowed by an ip address in one second. The number can be increased or decreased as per need. Connections over the defined number will be considered a dos attack.

```
3. setting ip address block time    


    cd /usr/local/ddos

you will see a file called ddos.conf, edit the file

    vi ddos.conf

and look for  ##### Number of seconds the banned ip should remain in blacklist.
BAN_PERIOD=60

change ban period to 


    BAN_PERIOD=600
```

Where 600 is the number of seconds the ip address will be blocked for, after that it will be released. This nmber can be changed as per need.

```
4. allow selected ip address to access the system without getting banned or restrictions.


    cd /usr/local/ddos

you will see a file called ignore.ip.list, edit the file

    vi ignore.ip.list


enter the following ip address to be unblocked

    127.0.0.1  ----> the localhost ip address
    92.235.247.186 ----> public ip address of the server (change as required)
```

Hope this helps a little.